# Cross apply not performant, convert to unpivot (or other)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, cross-apply

Cross apply is very slow when inserting large data sets, I think unpivot (or something else) might be more efficient but I can't figure out how to do it other than by using cross apply:

```
CREATE TABLE LocData
    (Airport varchar(5), City varchar(5), Country varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO LocData
    (Airport, City, Country)
VALUES
    ('LHR','LON','GB'),
    ('LGW','LON','GB'),
    ('LCY','LON','US'),
    ('JFK','NYC','US'),
    ('LGA','NYC','US'),
    ('EWR','NYC','US')
;

CREATE TABLE Travel
    (ID int, Dep varchar(5), Arr varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Travel
    (ID, Dep, Arr)
VALUES
    (1, 'LHR','JFK'),
    (2, 'LHR','EWR'),
    (3, 'LGA','LGW'),
    (4, 'LCY','EWR')
;
```

--the query

```
select * from Travel;

select 
    c.*
    from Travel t
    join LocData dep on dep.Airport=t.Dep
    join LocData arr on arr.Airport=t.Arr
    cross apply
    (
    values 
    (t.ID, dep.Airport, 0, arr.Airport, 0),
    (t.ID, dep.City, 1, arr.City, 1),
    (t.ID, dep.Country, 2, arr.Country, 2)
    ) c (ID, Dep, DepType, Arr, ArrType);
```

You can [test it here (SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5b34/2)

Comment: I just wanted to write something rude, because your question looked so extremely poor, but then I saw the fiddle link... I entered the code into the question, which will - for sure - bring you much better answers...

Comment: Are there any indexes / foreign keys? Are you really using the *3-char* airport code as the FK? What do you mean with *is very slow* and what are  *large data sets*?

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo wasn't sure if I should provide both, will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select c.*
from Travel t join
     LocData dep
     on dep.Airport = t.Dep join
     LocData arr
     on arr.Airport = t.Arr cross apply
     (values (t.ID, dep.Airport, 0, arr.Airport, 0),
             (t.ID, dep.City, 1, arr.City, 1),
             (t.ID, dep.Country, 2, arr.Country, 2)
    ) c(ID, Dep, DepType, Arr, ArrType);
```

This seems like a very efficient way to do what you want to do.  It should have good performance.

One thing that will improve performance is an index on `Locadata(airport)`.  You can also include the columns `city` and `country` (either `include` them or make them additional keys).  I would define the table using it as a primary key (which automatically creates the best type of index):

```
CREATE TABLE LocData (
    Airport varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    City varchar(5),
    Country varchar(5)
);
```

(Making the reasonable assumption that it is never `NULL` and never duplicated.)

In other words, I sincerely doubt that the `apply` affects performance.  The `join`s are much more likely to be the culprit.

Comment: You are right, the issue was nothing to do with the cross apply, it was down to a further operation outwith what I posted here. Now inserting 3mil+ in sub 40secs (was 19 minutes before). Happy days, false alarm.